# when one radio button is checked the other radio button should automatically get checked

Tags: javascript, php

I think this is simple one but i am not able to get the desired output.i have two radio buttons with different name.what i want is when one radio button is checked the other radio button  should automatically get checked and also the vice versa.

here is the simplified code snnipett.

```
 <tr>
   <?php
   for($mb=0;$mb<count($emaildetails);$mb++)
   { ?>
<td align="left" style="padding-right:30px;">
<input type="radio" id="contactkanaalid" name="contactkanaalid" 
value="<?php echo $emaildetails[$mb]['id']; ?>"
<?php if($mb == 0)echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> onclick="selectText(this)" />
</td>
<?php
} ?>
</tr>
```

and the other one

```
<tr>
<?php
for($mb=0;$mb<count($emaildetails);$mb++)
{ ?>
<td align="left" style="padding-right:30px;">
<input type="radio" id="kcontactkanaalid" name="kcontactkanaalid" 
    value="<?php echo $emaildetails[$mb]['id']; ?>"
    <?php if($mb == 0)echo   'checked="checked"'; ?> onclick="selectText(this)" />
    </td>
    <?php
    } ?>
    </tr>
```

and i am trying the following to achieve the output but no luck:

```
if(document.getElementById('contactkanaalid').checked){
document.getElementById('kcontactkanaalid').checked="checked";}
```

and the javacsript code

```
function selectText(t)
{
    selbu=t.value;
    <?php

        for($i=0;$i<count($emaildetails);$i++)
        {
            $buid=$emaildetails[$i]['id'];

         echo "if(selbu=='$buid'){";

        //the logic for radio buttons
            }
     ?>
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you need input type=checkbox? The whole idea about radio buttons is to have only one of them checked

Comment: That's a non-standard use of radio buttons and may prove very confusing for your users.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak that was a typo

Comment: @isherwood you are right but i am stuck in a situation that i have to implement this logic using radio button only

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get two radio buttons checked at the same time. With name you´re grouping radio options.

The use that you´re thinking for your radios is incorrect, and will cause UX issues, you must use checkboxes. But if you still want to achieve the result that you want, simply change the name attribute in one of your radios.

Regards.